# Can we convert the list into DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can any one tell me how to convert the List into data table in C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean generically? There is no automatic way to do it.

But you can manually:

```
class Person
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
...
}

var personsList = new List<Person>();
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("ÏD", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
...

foreach (var person in personsList)
{
  dataTable.Rows.Add(person.ID, person.FirstName...)
}
```